# algorithm to find the nth character of DA,B(n)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Here is the description of my problem. For any two string variables, A and B, we define FA,B to be the sequence (A,B,AB,BAB,ABBAB,...) in which each term is the concatenation of the previous two.

Further, we define DA,B(n) to be the nth digit in the first term of FA,B that contains at least n digits.

Example :

Let A="1415", B="8979". n = 10 We wish to find DA,B(n), say.

The first few terms of FA,B are:

"1415"

"8979"

"14158979"

"897914158979"

"9" is the answer

Write an algorithm to find the nth character of DA,B(n)

These things are need to fulfill when write a solution.

1. The return type should be a string.
2. getNthPosition("1415","8979",10) Should equal to 9
3. getNthPosition("abc","435d",100) Should equal to b
4. The answer should be valid for any given input

1 and 2 requirments are complteted but i don't have idea about how to do 3rd requirment. any suggession. Thanks.

here is my code:

```
function getNthPosition(a,b,n) {
let output = '';  
 var tot2,ans;

  tot2 = b + a;
  ans = b+a+b; 

  for(var i = 0; i<=ans.length - 1; i++){


    output += ans[i].split("").sort().join('');


    output += "";
  }

  var nNumber = ans[n - 1];

  return nNumber;

}

console.log(getNthPosition("1415","8979",10));
```

Comment: What are limits for n value/string lengths?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might use an array of strings that you push to on each iteration, so that you can retrieve the string from the array's `length - 2` and `length - 1` to concatenate together to construct the next one:

```js
function getNthPosition(a, b, n) {
  const strs = [a, b];
  // input is 1-indexed, get a variable that's 0-indexed:
  const targetIndex = n - 1;
  while (strs[strs.length - 1].length < targetIndex) {
    const newStr = strs[strs.length - 2] + strs[strs.length - 1];
    strs.push(newStr);
  }
  const last = strs.pop();
  return last[targetIndex];
}

console.log(getNthPosition("1415", "8979", 10));
console.log(getNthPosition("abc", "435d", 100));
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. got the idea and solved the issue.

Comment: It would be too wasteful to build all these long strings for large values of offset.

Comment: @MBo The time complexity is `O(log n)` - it won't take long at all to get a string of the desired index, since string length ~doubles for every 2 iterations. Strings are not at all memory-expensive either

Comment: @CertainPerformance We have to allocate O(n) memory, so complexity is linear. (Of course, I don't know author limitations)

Comment: @MBo If you have an idea of how to make a better algorithm, feel free to post it as an answer